# Can't get the list of indexes of aws elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, indexing

I have this python script:

```
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
         credentials.secret_key,
         session.region_name, 'es',
         session_token=credentials.token)



es_client = Elasticsearch(
                        "vpc-mydomain-elasticsearch-xxxxxxxxx.region.es.amazonaws.com:9200",
                        http_auth=awsauth,
                        use_ssl=False,
                        verify_certs=False,
                        connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)

print(es_client.info())
```

When I run the script I get this error:

```
    raise ConnectionTimeout('TIMEOUT', str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeout(HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.0.2.2', port=3128): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))
```

The security group of the cluster has the port 9200 open for 0.0.0.0/0.
( **10.0.2.2 is the ip address of my vagrant machine, the port 3128 is the listening port of cntlm** )
How to get this work ?

**EDIT**

I also tried this but it didn't work:

```
 curl -XGET https://vpc-mydomain-elasticsearch-xxxxxxxxx.region.es.amazonaws.com:9200/_cat/indices?v
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Comment: what is these host='10.0.2.2', port=3128? It seem you get error for this ip and port.

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is the ip address of my vagrant machine, the port 3128 is the proxy port of cntlm

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solutions:

- Change the default timeout of 10 seconds to request_timeout=n where n could be a number more than 10, ideally 30. Increase if error persists.
- Check your config/elasticsearch.yml to ensure that the http.proxy variable points to the right address.
- Try changing the port from 9200 to 443.
- Change use_ssl to True.

Hope this helps.